# Mongoose update Query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hello All I am attempting to make an update using mongoose and I can't seem to get it working. This is the data that I am saving.

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var DataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  advisorEmail: {
    type: String
  },
  data: {
    type: Array
  },
  client: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  accountBalance: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  AccountValue: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  moneyMarket: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  buyingPower: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  netBalance: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  advisorPercentage: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  }
});

var Data = mongoose.model('Table', DataSchema);
module.exports = Data;
```

Below will be the code I am writing to be able to update the data array

```
Data.update({
"advisorEmail":"Travis@travis.com"
}, 
{"$push":
    { "data":{"client": "Tester", "accountBalance": 21342,     
"description": "test From Nodejs", "AccountValue": 123234,     
"moneyMarket": 11000, "buyingPower": 01, "netBalance": 10, 
"advisorPercentage": 24}}}, function(err, updateData){
       if (err) throw (err);
       console.log(updateData);
    });
```

There are no errors and this is the console.log that I get back from "updateData."

```
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
```

But when I take the same structure and go into my local mongodb and do

```
 db.tables.update({
     "advisorEmail": "Travis@travis.com"
 }, {
     "$push": {
         "data": {
             "client": "bobby",
             "accountBalance": 123,
             "description": "TravisPUTO",
             "AccountValue": 123,
             "moneyMarket": 1000,
             "buyingPower": 0,
             "netBalance": 0,
             "advisorPercentage": 1
         }
     }
 })
```

it works completely fine and says this..

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

is this a mongoose issue? I'm not really sure what's wrong.

Thank you for anything you may be able to do to help me!

Comment: You're model name appears to be `Data`. Have you actually defined it like `mongoose.model('Data', dataSchema, "tables")`? Because if you have not then you're likely pointing to the wrong collection name, or possibly even the wrong database. See the `n: 0` there refers to the "number matched" or `nMatched` from the shell. So you are either pointing at the wrong place or your mongoose schema is incorrect and changing the input values.

Comment: I use Data.find() and that works so I know it's the correct table. all I do is switch Data.update() to db.tables.update() and copy the query over to mongod in my terminal and it works fine. So I know the code for mongo is correct but would it switch to a different syntax with Mongoose?

Comment: Syntax is exactly the same. The schema will be wrong. Show your schema within your question.

Comment: @NeilLunn I updated the question with the schema.

Comment: What about the other model? Do you actually have `data: [DataSchema]` or do you have `data: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Data' }]` or similar? Only one of those is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your schema with additional fields.

```
advisorEmail : {type: String},
data: { type: Array },
```

so mongoose identified fields you update.

Comment: Yup this ended up being the reason why! I didn't realize I needed these as well since I wasn't actually inputting that data into the database as it's already going to be there. I thought only thing that had to be in the schema is data you're saving. Thank you!

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct  if it solved your problem